# Render two components in reagent / reframe

Tags: clojurescript, reagent, re-frame

I have some code:

```clj
(defn second-panel []
    [:div
     [:h1 "Hello "]
     ])

(defn root-container []
  (second-panel)
  (let [name (re-frame/subscribe [::subs/name])]
    [:div
     [:h1 "Hello from " @name]
     ]))
```

but only the `root-container` component renders. Why is my `second-panel` function not rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `(second-panel)` to your div. The return value of `(second-panel)` is currently ignored.

```
(defn root-container []
  (let [name (re-frame/subscribe [::subs/name])]
    [:div
     (second-panel)
     [:h1 "Hello from " @name]
     ]))
```

Comment: Could I use your example and just ignore the first time `(second-panel)` gets called? I don't understand why that works.

Comment: yeah, I removed the first call to second-panel.
Clojure/Lisp uses expressions. If you have two expressions in a row, the result of the first expression is ignored unless there is a side-effect happening in the first expression.
It takes some getting used to.
There's a section in https://clojure.org/guides/learn/syntax that explains expressions vs. statements

Comment: the return value of `root-container` is the vector starting with :div which is what is getting rendered.
The output of calling `second-panel` in your original source code is not part of that vector and thus doesn't get rendered.

Answer (score 3):

The correct solution to returning multiple virtual DOM elements from a function without wrapping them in a container element is to use a [Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html). In `reagent` this is handled by the `:<>` special keyword.

```clj
(defn second-panel []
  [:div
   [:h1 "Hello "]])

(defn root-container []
  (let [name (re-frame/subscribe [::subs/name])]
    [:<>
     [second-panel]
     [:div
      [:h1 "Hello from " @name]
      ]]))

;; or, with the nested let. both variants are fine.

(defn root-container []
  [:<>
   [second-panel]
   (let [name (re-frame/subscribe [::subs/name])]
     [:div
      [:h1 "Hello from " @name]
      ])])
```

There is also a different in `(second-panel)` and `[second-panel]` since `(second-panel)` will actually call the function directly which means it will not behave like a regular reagent function but instead become part of the caller. You should prefer the `[second-panel]` notation for all "component" type functions.